# Uncaught type error : Cannot read value 'name' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, json, formatting, syntax-error

Actually I am having a global JSON, when I am trying to parse its value in loop, it is showing me error "uncaught type error : Cannot read value 'name' of undefined". I have tried a lot but I am still not able to figure out any solution for it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   

var productJSON = [
                    {id:"1001",name:"Hopper1",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1002",name:"Hopper2",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1003",name:"Hopper3",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1004",name:"Hopper4",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1005",name:"Hopper5",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1006",name:"Hopper6",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1007",name:"Hopper7",image:"images/290161k.jpg"},
                    {id:"1008",name:"Hopper8",image:"images/290161k.jpg"}
                  ];
var a=0;
for(var i=0;i<productJSON.length;i++){
    var pagedisplay = '';
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
            var generatedProductDisplay = '';

            generatedProductDisplay = '<div id="'+productJSON[a].id+'" class="productDiv"><a class="productLink" href="#"><center><div class="productImage"><img src="'+productJSON[a].image+'" width="100%" height="200px" alt="'+productJSON[a].name+'"></div><div><p class="productName">'+productJSON[a].name+'</p></div></center></a></div>';

            pagedisplay = pagedisplay+generatedProductDisplay;
            a++;
        }
        pagedisplay = pagedisplay+'<br/>';
        $(".productDisplay").append(pagedisplay);
    }   

$(".productDiv").live("click",function(){
    alert("Hello"); 
});
   });
```

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to Nitin Agro Industries, Chhatarpur</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="productsDisplay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

 <body>
 <center>
 <div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="centerContent">
  <h1>Explore our Product Catalog</h1>
  <div class="centerText">
    <center>
      <div class="hideShowDiv">
        skdddddddddddd
      </div>
      <div class="productDisplay"></div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How could we possibly help you without seeing the json and the code ?

Comment: Stating the obvious: The problem is that you are accessing a property which does not exist. The solution is to either not access it or make sure that it exists.

Comment: You are increasing `a` inside the inner loop. So in each iteration of the outer loop, you are increasing `a` twice. Eventually `a` will have a larger value than the number of elements in the array (when `i` is `productJSON.length / 2`) and you are trying to access indexes which don't exist in the array. What's the reason for the inner loop? If you want proper help, you should state what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sir what I want to do is that the loops processes every element of array just once, and display 2 products per row. So I used two loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the property is not defined at that point. So check if you have defined the property.

The question obviously needs the source-code to be answered. Please put them.

**EDIT**

Its an out of bound problem. Change this line:

```
generatedProductDisplay = '<div id="'+productJSON[a].id+'" class="productDiv"><a class="productLink" href="#"><center><div class="productImage"><img src="'+productJSON[a].image+'" width="100%" height="200px" alt="'+productJSON[a].name+'"></div><div><p class="productName">'+productJSON[a].name+'</p></div></center></a></div>';
```

`a` contains value out of the range of the array. Change it to `i`.

As you have not stated your logic. I assume that the inner loop does nothing (from what i can derive) and suggest this:

```
for(var i=0;i<productJSON.length;i++){
    var pagedisplay = '';
        var generatedProductDisplay = '';

        generatedProductDisplay = '<div id="'+productJSON[i].id+'" class="productDiv"><a class="productLink" href="#"><center><div class="productImage"><img src="'+productJSON[i].image+'" width="100%" height="200px" alt="'+productJSON[i].name+'"></div><div><p class="productName">'+productJSON[i].name+'</p></div></center></a></div>';

        pagedisplay = pagedisplay+generatedProductDisplay;
        pagedisplay = pagedisplay+'<br/>';
        $(".productDisplay").append(pagedisplay);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

As i still didnt understand your inner loop, here is my take on it:

Without inner loop:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/guSLL/
$(document).ready(function() {

    var productJSON = [
        {
        id: "1001",
        name: "Hopper1",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1002",
        name: "Hopper2",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1003",
        name: "Hopper3",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1004",
        name: "Hopper4",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1005",
        name: "Hopper5",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1006",
        name: "Hopper6",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1007",
        name: "Hopper7",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1008",
        name: "Hopper8",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"}
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < productJSON.length; i++) {
        var pagedisplay = '';
        generatedProductDisplay = '<div id="' + productJSON[i].id + '" class="productDiv"><a class="productLink" href="#"><center><div class="productImage"><img src="' + productJSON[i].image + '" width="100%" height="200px" alt="' + productJSON[i].name + '"></div><div><p class="productName">' + productJSON[i].name + '</p></div></center></a></div>';
        pagedisplay = pagedisplay + generatedProductDisplay;
        pagedisplay = pagedisplay + '<br/>';
        $(".productDisplay").append(pagedisplay);
    }

    $(".productDiv").live("click", function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

With inner loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/guSLL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var productJSON = [
        {
        id: "1001",
        name: "Hopper1",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1002",
        name: "Hopper2",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1003",
        name: "Hopper3",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1004",
        name: "Hopper4",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1005",
        name: "Hopper5",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1006",
        name: "Hopper6",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1007",
        name: "Hopper7",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"},
    {
        id: "1008",
        name: "Hopper8",
        image: "images/290161k.jpg"}
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < productJSON.length;) {

        var pagedisplay = '';
        for (j = 0; j < 2 && i < productJSON.length; j++, i++) {
            generatedProductDisplay = '<div id="' + productJSON[i].id + '" class="productDiv"><a class="productLink" href="#"><center><div class="productImage"><img src="' + productJSON[i].image + '" width="100%" height="200px" alt="' + productJSON[i].name + '"></div><div><p class="productName">' + productJSON[i].name + '</p></div></center></a></div>';
            pagedisplay = pagedisplay + generatedProductDisplay;
            pagedisplay = pagedisplay + '<br/>';

        }
        $(".productDisplay").append(pagedisplay);
    }

    $(".productDiv").live("click", function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear Sir the inner loop is for controlling the number of columns in the webpage. means I can control the number of products to (2-3) etc.

Comment: @AnkurJain Then inorder to answer this, we need the HTML markup also. Also state your logic of what you are trying to accomplish. This is required inorder to find what is exactly wrong. 1 Golden rule is to imagine yourself answering this question and asking yourself "do i have all the requred information to answer this?"

Comment: thanks a lot for ur suggestion sir, I will be carefull next-time, now I have pasted the whole code. U can check it out now.

Comment: @AnkurJain, you did paste the code, but you never explained the reason behind your logic.So AGAIN i am guessing. lol anyway i have updated my codes. Have a look if that's what you want.

Comment: @AnkurJain I am not a "sir" :P but glad could help you.